# How to convert HTML form to an editable pdf using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

Hi I am a JS beginner but I have a use case, where I need to convert an HTML form into an editable pdf. Such that, the generated pdf will then be passed to a js script that fills the pdf template using pdftk package.

I tried using htm2pdf but the generated pdf is image scanned and not an editable form. Can anyone please help me, I have been trying this for over a week and couldn't find a suitable solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

you want a client-side solution to generate PDF documents, JavaScript is the easiest way to convert HTML to PDF.
There are various JavaScript library is available for generating PDF from HTML. js PDF is one of the best libraries to convert HTML to PDF using JavaScript.

```
<!-- jsPDF library -->
<script src="js/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

Note that: You don’t need to download the jsPDF library separately, all the required files are included in our source code package.
var doc = new jsPDF();

```
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript to generate a PDF.');



   // Add new page
    doc.addPage();
    doc.text(20, 20, 'Visit CodexWorld.com');

    // Save the PDF
    doc.save('document.pdf');
    HTML Code:
    <div id="content">
        <!-- HTML contnet goes here -->
    </div>

    <div id="elementH"></div>
    JavaScript Code:
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var elementHTML = $('#contnet').html();
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#elementH': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };
   doc.fromHTML(elementHTML, 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });

// Save the PDF
   doc.save('sample-document.pdf');
   var doc = new jsPDF();
    
   doc.text(20, 20, 'This is the default font.');

    doc.setFont("courier");
    doc.setFontType("normal");
    doc.text(20, 30, 'This is courier normal.');

    doc.setFont("times");
    doc.setFontType("italic");
    doc.text(20, 40, 'This is times italic.');

    doc.setFont("helvetica");
    doc.setFontType("bold");
    doc.text(20, 50, 'This is helvetica bold.');

    doc.setFont("courier");
    doc.setFontType("bolditalic");
    doc.text(20, 60, 'This is courier bolditalic.');

    // Save the PDF
    doc.save('document.pdf');
```